# QAF Allure Report not generating

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, allure, qaf

Allure Report not generating in QAF framework (testng). I have configured the below config in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-cucumber5-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also added below config inside maven-surefire-plugin

```
<allure.results.directory>${project.basedir}/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
```

Note: I do understand QAF provides inbuilt reporting, but we require this framework to be integrated to Allure.

Expecting Allure reports (json) to be generated.

Note: I'm using QAF 4.0.0-RC1